# Set CSS style to elements with specific styles

Tags: css, css-float, margins

I have lots of images in my content with preset styles like `<img src="" style="float:left">` or `<img src="" style="float:right">`

I would like to set different margins for them depending on how they are floated. Is it possible to set CSS style for images with preset styles?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly the (CSS3) selector you are after is the *attribute contains* selector:

```
img[style*="float:left;"] { margin: ; }
img[style*="float:right;"] { margin: ; }
```

Unlike Mr Lister's answer it will work even if the element has other inline styles. That said, I much prefer Lollero's answer of using classes and applying your margins that way; it'll be 100% browser compatible!

Comment: I find it strange that this works, as this example has semicolons, which the original question didn't! But OK, I stand defeated.

Comment: @MrLister I am presuming the code shown in the example is a demo, the actual code in use must have semicolons as is standard :)

Comment: Note that you don't need semicolons at the end; a semicolon is a property separator, not a terminator.

Comment: @MrLister Indeed it isn't required but is "the norm", a de-facto standard if you please. This situation is a perfect example why: if a semicolon wasn't included at the end of the css rule, then the following code wouldn't be matched against the above attribute selector: `style="width:300px; float:right"`. Granted, in this situation it makes no difference as the semicolon could be removed from the selector, although maybe if you were using properties like repeat and repeat-x it would. Writing your css consistently helps alot when you run into situations like these!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you'd want to do it that way, so I'm going to suggest this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZDjWT/

HTML:

```
<img class="left" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/200/100/" alt="" />
<img class="right" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/200/100/" alt="" />
```

CSS:

```
.left {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
```

Comment: There is too many images already set with style="float:left", no chance to change them all. Just wanted to figured out how to make it automatically.

Comment: @OlegsKrisons If you have a decent editor, you can replace everything that has for example: `style="float:left"` with `class="left"` This of course asuming that youre code is as simple as your example is in the question. ( Of course when replacing things you might want to make hooks so you'll be sure that you're replacing exactly what you need to.. like `style="float: left;" alt="` replaced with `class="left" alt="` )

Comment: @OlegsKrisons If you want maximum browser compatibility then this is the way to go. Replace-all works wonders... (upped)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as the style is only `"float:left"` and doesn't include other properties, or whitespace around the colon, you can write `img[style='float:left']` in your CSS.

If the style attribute can include other things too, you might be better off using Javascript to add the properties. (Check for `.. .style.float`)

**Edit**: and as Pekka says, the CSS doesn't work in all browsers. Maybe adding a class to the images is the better idea after all!

Comment: As you say, this is very, very shaky because the `style` property has to match exactly; also, this isn't supported by IE7 (although thankfully, that is becoming less and less of an issue.)

Comment: @Pekka: Do you mean IE7 has issues with attribute selectors and the `style` attribute? I've heard that it confuses attributes and properties, but I'm not sure how exactly.

Comment: @BoltClock ohh, I had this wrong - I thought IE7 didn't support attribute selectors at all, which is not true. Mr Lister, I stand corrected! So it's just IE6 that isn't supporting this - and that, I'd say, we can ignore now.

Comment: @Pekka: AFAIK, IE7 supports all attribute selectors in CSS2 and CSS3, except with the attribute/property quirk I mentioned.

Comment: Yeah, I also know that IE7 has many CSS issues, which were solved with IE8. I don't remember which specific ones (so I took your remark aft face value), but I can't test now; I'm at home and running under Linux. I can do some checking when I get back to work though.